# Python Scatter Plot connected with line, but why there is a bottom line?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I'm connecting list of (x,y) points on 1 chart, with scatter plot. It does connect all these points together, but also generates a line at the bottom.

Here is my sample code (I'm using iPython):

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats, integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(color_codes=True)

mc_time_lst1 = [[0, 8], [1, 12], [2, 18]]
mc_time_lst2 = [[0, 10], [1, 9], [2, 5]]
mc_time_lst3 = [[0, 11], [1, 8], [2, 17]]

plt.plot(mc_time_lst1, 'o-', label='line1')
plt.plot(mc_time_lst2, '-*', label='line2')
plt.plot(mc_time_lst3, '-D', label='line3')
plt.legend();
```

This is what I got:

As you can see, there is a golden line (in fact that's 3 lines) under the real 3 lines I want. Then when there are multiple lines, look at the legend can be confusing.

[image]

Is there any way to remove that bottom line? Or remove the legend for that bottom line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to give x axis data as it is `0,1,2..` and so on.

You can simply write the following code

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mc_time_lst1 = [ 8,  12,  18]
mc_time_lst2 = [ 10,  9,  5]
mc_time_lst3 = [ 11,  8,  17]
plt.plot(mc_time_lst1, 'o-', label='line1')
plt.plot(mc_time_lst2, '-*', label='line2')
plt.plot(mc_time_lst3, '-D', label='line3')
plt.legend();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data has the wrong format. The plotting function expects values either for only `y` or for `x` and `y` separately. I.e. you would do

```
plt.plot([0,1,2],[8,12,18])
```

or in this case simply

```
plt.plot([8,12,18])
```

To plot the given data from the question, you may rearange them as follows:

```
#%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats, integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(color_codes=True)

mc_time_lst1 = [[0, 8], [1, 12], [2, 18]]
mc_time_lst2 = [[0, 10], [1, 9], [2, 5]]
mc_time_lst3 = [[0, 11], [1, 8], [2, 17]]

x1,y1 = zip(*mc_time_lst1)
x2,y2 = zip(*mc_time_lst2)
x3,y3 = zip(*mc_time_lst3)

plt.plot(x1,y1, 'o-', label='line1')
plt.plot(x2,y2, '-*', label='line2')
plt.plot(x3,y3, '-D', label='line3')
plt.legend()
```

[image]